# Resource image in to Blob for attachment

Tags: apex, blob, blob.topdf

I have a trigger method after update on Opportunity. I am trying to insert attachment after closing the opp.

```
 private void createOppAttachments(list<Opportunity> opps) {
         Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
         List<Attachment> attList = new List<Attachment>();
         for(Opportunity op:opps){
             if (op.StageName == 'Closed Won')
                 oppIds.add(op.Id);
                 //MergePDF_Controller.Save(op.Id, op.Name);
                 //MergePDF_Controller.generatePdf(op.Id, op.Name);

         }
        StaticResource sr = [SELECT Id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'logi' LIMIT 1];
         //String logobody = sr.Body.toString();
         //System.debug(Logginglevel.error,'******************logobody : '+sr );
         if(oppIds != null && !oppIds.isEmpty()) {
              for(Opportunity opp : [ SELECT Id, Name,Image__c, Account.Name, 
                                     (SELECT Quantity, UnitPrice, TotalPrice, 
                                      PricebookEntry.Name, PricebookEntry.Product2.Family FROM 
                                      OpportunityLineItems) 
                                      FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN:oppIds]){  
                   String logo='<img src="/resource/08146000000AiqO/logi" />';
                   logo.replaceall('src','');
                   String bodyStr = '';
                   System.debug(Logginglevel.error,'******************opp prod: '+opp.OpportunityLineItems);   
                   for(OpportunityLineItem ol:opp.OpportunityLineItems){
                       bodyStr += logo+'Product Name      : ' + ol.PricebookEntry.Name+ '\r\n'+'Total Price      : ' + ol.TotalPrice+ '\r\n'+'<br/>';
                       bodyStr += '\r\n';

                   }  
                   System.debug(Logginglevel.error,'******************String: '+bodyStr );               
                 bodyStr +='<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/748187442318974976/CDvq8db7.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">';
                 string td1='"border:1px solid green; width=200px;"';
                 string td2='"width=200px; border:1px solid green; background-color:red; color:white; font-weight:bold;"';               
                 string tdHead='"border:1px solid green; width=200px; color:white; background-color:green; font-weight:bold;"';
                 String contents = '<html><body>'+bodyStr+'</body></html>';

                 Blob pdfBlob = Blob.toPDF(bodyStr );
                 Attachment at = new Attachment(parentId = opp.id, name=opp.name + '.pdf', body = pdfBlob);

                 attList.add(at);                 
             }
              insert attList;       
         } 

    }
```

> Error: System.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred while parsing the input string.

How do I insert a logo image in the attachment body?

Comment: Not sure if this is causing your error, but when creating `contents` you aren't actually concatenating the `bodyStr` variable.  It should be `'<html><body>'+bodyStr+'</body></html>'`

Comment: I did this, "String contents = '<html><body>'+bodyStr+'</body></html>';". Still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Does it give you a line number?

Comment: Additionally, this question might provide some helpful resources: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7575/convert-html-to-pdf-in-apex

Comment: error occurs at "Blob pdfBlob = Blob.toPDF(bodyStr );"

Comment: It looks like you can't include external URIs in the static HTML that you pass to the `Blob` method.  This link should get you where you need to go.  It involves creating a new VF pages with a `renderAs="pdf"` tag on it, and getting that page content as a PDF.  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BVU3IAO

Comment: I found this useful link, I will try this. https://jungleeforce.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/generate-a-pdf-and-attach-it-to-record-from-a-trigger-in-salesforce/