# CommandButton action method doesn't display expected page

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

I have a custom controller and a visualforce page that works perfectly besides when there isn't a duplicate and the user needs to be taken to the account edit page (which is written in the controller). For some reason, when there isn't a duplicate the "click to Proceed" button does not take you to that page. Help would be much appreciated! Thank you :)

Account Duplicate VF Page

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountDupeCatch6">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Information">
   <apex:form >
      <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
       <tr>
       <td style="font-weight:bold;">Account Name<br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!NewAccount.Name}"/>
       </td>
       </tr>
       <td style="font-weight:bold;">Shipping Street<br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!NewAccount.ShippingStreet}"/>
       </td>
       <td style="font-weight:bold;">City<br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!NewAccount.ShippingCity}" required="true"/>
       </td>
       <td style="font-weight:bold;">State<br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!NewAccount.ShippingState}" required="true"/>
       </td>
       <td style="font-weight:bold;">Zip<br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!NewAccount.ShippingPostalCode}"/>
       </td>
    </table>

         <apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" value="Click here to proceed" status="status" reRender="ProceedPanel" />  


     <!-- Display error message -->
     <apex:outputPanel id="ProceedPanel">
         <apex:pagemessage strength="2" title="Duplicate!!" severity="error" detail="This Account Name Already Exists !!!" rendered="{!errormsg}"/><!-- End of error message -->
           <apex:pageblocktable rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(existingaccountlist))}" value="{!existingaccountlist}" var="acct">
                          <apex:column headervalue="Select">
                                   <apex:commandlink action="{!SelectName}">
                                       <input type="radio" name="AccountSel" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.RadioButtonValue}')"/>
                                       <apex:param name="accID" value="{!acct.id}" assignTo="{!accId}"/>
                                   </apex:commandlink>                                         
                          </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Account Name"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.Name}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Type"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.recordtype.name}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Flag"> <apex:outputfield value="{!acct.Status_Flag__c}" />  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Customer ID"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.CustomerMasterID__c}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Shipping Street"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.shippingstreet}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="City"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.shippingcity}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="State"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.shippingstate}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Zip"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.shippingpostalcode}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Parent Account"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.parent.name}"/>  </apex:column>         
           </apex:pageblocktable>

            <apex:commandButton action="{!Proceed}" value="Create Prospect Anyway" id="proceedButton" rendered="{!IF(chkdup.size > 0, true, false)}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onkeydown" disabled="false"/>
     </apex:outputPanel>
 </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class AccountDupeCatch6 {

public boolean errormsg=false;
public String AccountId=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
public String aname;
public String ashippingstreet;
public String acity;
public String astate;
public String azip;
public Id accId {get; set;}
public List<Account> chkdup {get; set;}
public Account newaccount= new Account();

 public AccountDupeCatch6(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
   {
     chkdup = new list<account>();
   }
 public account getnewaccount()
   {
     return newaccount;
   }
 public account getexistingaccount()
  {
     if (chkdup!= NULL)
  {
     if(chkdup.size()>0)
        return chkdup[0];
   else
         return null;
  }
   else
         return null;
}

 public list<account> getexistingaccountlist()
   {
     if (chkdup!= NULL)
   {
     if(chkdup.size()>0)
        return chkdup;
    else
        return null;
   }
    else
        return null;
}

 public pagereference Next()
   {          
      chkdup=Database.query('Select name,id,recordtype.name,CustomerMasterID__c,status_flag__c,shippingstreet,shippingcity,shippingstate,shippingpostalcode,parent.name from Account where Name like \'%' + newaccount.name + '%\' AND (ShippingStreet like \'%' + newaccount.shippingstreet + '%\' OR ShippingCity like \'%' + newaccount.shippingcity + '%\' OR ShippingState like \'%' + newaccount.shippingstate + '%\' OR  ShippingPostalCode like \'%' + newaccount.shippingpostalcode + '%\') Order By Status_Flag__c');       
if(chkdup.size()==0)

 {
      System.debug('Hello');
      String aname=newaccount.Name;
      String ashippingstreet=newaccount.shippingstreet;
      String acity=newaccount.shippingcity;
      String astate=newaccount.shippingstate;
      String azip=newaccount.shippingpostalcode;
      Pagereference newaccount1 = new Pagereference('/001/e?nooverride=true&acc2='+aname+'&acc18street='+ashippingstreet+'&acc18city='+acity+'&acc18state='+astate+'&acc18zip='+azip);
       newaccount1.setredirect(true);
       return newaccount1;
 }
  else
 {
       errormsg=true;
       return null;
 }

 }

public pagereference SelectName() {
    return new Pagereference('/' + accId);

   //Pagereference chkdup = new Pagereference('/' + chkdup[0].Id);
   //return chkdup;
}


public pagereference Proceed() {
      String aname=newaccount.Name;
      String ashippingstreet=newaccount.shippingstreet;
      String acity=newaccount.shippingcity;
      String astate=newaccount.shippingstate;
      String azip=newaccount.shippingpostalcode;
      Pagereference newaccount2 = new Pagereference('/001/e?nooverride=true&acc2='+aname+'&acc18street='+ashippingstreet+'&acc18city='+acity+'&acc18state='+astate+'&acc18zip='+azip+'');
      return newaccount2; 
          }

public boolean geterrormsg()
{
  return errormsg;
}  

}
```

Comment: I suggest you add `System.debug(chkdup);` straight after the query in the `Next` method to see what the actual result is including the field values (as it is probably not what your are expecting). That is only thing I can see in that method that would cause your problem.

Comment: I added a system.debug('hello'); to my class and I received the message in the debug log, so that tells me the soql query is working

Comment: OK. Looks like you are making progress on the URL so good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code fragment in your next() action method

```
Pagereference newaccount1 = new Pagereference('/001/e?nooverride=1&acc2='+aname+'&acc18street='+ashippingstreet+'&acc18city='+acity+'&acc18state='+astate+'&acc18zip='+azip+'');
  return newaccount1;
```

is missing the redirect

```
Pagereference newaccount1 = new Pagereference('/001/e?nooverride=1&acc2='+aname+'&acc18street='+ashippingstreet+'&acc18city='+acity+'&acc18state='+astate+'&acc18zip='+azip);
  newAccount1.setRedirect(true);
  return newaccount1;
```

BTW - best practice would be to use variable names like newAcctPg for variables of type PageReference

BTW2 - I changed the nooverride=true to nooverride=1 in your URL; [see this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/common-url-parameters) . This will ensure you are going to the standard Account New page which I believe is your intent

BTW3 - Removed your trailing single quote

Comment: I did add the newAccount1.setRedirect(true); where you had told me and it still didn't work

Comment: @NewbieDeveloper27 - please update your code in the original post

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I tried your updated answer by switching that out, but it didn't work. I think this error in my chrome developer console might be the problem, but I don't know how to fix it: Refused to display 'https://cs9.salesforce.com/001/e?acc18city=Minneapolis&acc18state=MN&acc18street=null&acc18zip=null&acc2=Shasta+Hospital&nooverride=true' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: When I inspected that URL - it looks like `https://cs9.salesforce.com/001/e?acc18city=Minneapolis&acc18state=MN&acc18street=null&acc18zip=null&acc2=Shasta+Hospital&nooverride=true%27`   Why is there a trailing %27 (single quote) ?

Comment: Dropped the +'' from the zip in the URL and it gave me the same error message:   Refused to display 'https://cs9.salesforce.com/001/e?acc18city=Minneapolis&acc18state=MN&acc18street=null&acc18zip=null&acc2=Shasta+Hospital&nooverride=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "https://c.cs9.visual.force.com" from accessing a frame at "https://c.cs9.visual.force.com".  The frame being accessed is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag. VFDevModeWithViewstate.js:21

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

Comment: I ended up taking the reRender="ProceedPanel" out of the first command button and it ended up working.

Comment: Glad you found it. Your `next` action method, when it returns null, will cause the page to refresh. I know that one use of rerender on commandButton is to pass child apex:param with assignTo= attributes to the controller (which you are not doing)