# Need help to make V.F page return back to Standard page on Save

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is a very lengthy question since I want to explain exactly what is happening.

I have 2 V.F page and controller on **SAMPLE** object **(V.F Page names : SampleObjectPage(SOP) and RedirectPage(RP))**. Currently the **SOP** page is written to override both **NEW/EDIT** button. Also the **view page** is redirected to this **SOP** page with the help of **RP** page. The redirection is happening with the help of **RP page** since if we override the **SOP page with the VIEW button** then it is opening the record in the **EDIT mode rather in the VIEW mode**. This must be happening due to the way the code is written. It is opening up as below.

[image: When The record is viewed.]

If the redirection is happening through 2 V.F pages, then it is in between showing the Standard page and then finally opening up the **SOP page** as below.

[image]

Now the second option which I tried was to remove the V.F page from the Standard page. And just redirect to the **SOP V.F** page upon clicking **NEW/EDIT/CLONE** buttons. But this is also creating issue upon clicking the **Save/Cancel** buttons. It is then again redirecting back to the **SOP Page** rather than Standard page due to the way the code is already written. I have tried many things to redirect it back to the Standard page but nothing succeeded.

Here I am just posting the part of code which works upon Save/Cancel buttons since full code is very long. I want that upon cancel/save it should redirect to standard page.

**Controller**

```
public class SampleOrderExtension{
    public SampleOrderExtension soExtObj { get { return this; } private set; }  
    public Sample__c soRecord { get;set; }
    public Sample_Detail__c slRecord{ get;set; }
    public boolean recordSaved { get;set; }
    public String recSaved { get;set; }
    public String clone { get;set; }
    public String edit { get;set; }
    public list<User> currentUser { get;set; }
    public boolean isStandardUser { get;set; }
    public ZEND__c ZendRec { get;set; }

    public SampleOrderExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
       // std = stdController; //Added on 7/Oct/2016
        fromAcc = false;
        fromOpp = false;
        notIsROR = false;
        noZend = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('noZend');
        recSaved = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordSaved');
        clone = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('clone');
        edit = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('edit');       
        accId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CFlookupfieldID_lkid');
        oppId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId');
        opptyId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CFlookupfieldID_lkid');

    //There is a lot of code here to insert/save sample records
    }

    //Method written for Save button
    public PageReference save(){
        ZEND__c Z=New ZEND__c();
        if(!isNullOrEmpty(oppId)){
            soRecord.Opportunity__c = oppId;
            soRecord.from_Opportunity__c = true;
        }

    //Some IF-ELSE Statements
    PageReference pr = null;

        try{
        if(!isNullOrEmpty(zend)){                        
            //Z=[select id from ZEND__c where Name=:zend limit 1];

            //soRecord.ZEND__c = Z.id;
              soRecord.ZEND__c = zend;               
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
            soRecord.ZEND__c = null;
            }                

            if(!isNullOrEmpty(soRecord.Ship_to__c)){
            if(soRecord.Status__c != 'Ready for Processing'){
                soRecord.Status__c = 'Saved, Not Submitted';
            }
            if(edit == '1'){           
                update soRecord;
            }else if(clone == '1'){                            
                soRecord = soRecord.clone(false, true);            
                insert soRecord;
            }else{                      
                if(soRecord.ZEND__c==null){                   
               }                   
                insert soRecord;            
            }

            recordSaved = true;            
            pr = Page.SampleOrderPage;
            pr.getParameters().put('id', soRecord.Id);
            pr.getParameters().put('recordSaved', 'true');
            return pr.setRedirect(true);    
        }
        return pr; //Need to modify this so that redirection happen to Standard Page.
    }

    public PageReference cancel(){
        PageReference pr = null;
        if(clone == '1' || edit == '1'){
            pr = Page.SampleOrderPage;
            pr.getParameters().put('id', soRecord.Id);
            pr.getParameters().put('recordSaved', 'true');
            pr.setRedirect(true);
        }else{
            pr = new PageReference('/object 3 digit id/o');
        }

        return pr; //Need to modify this so that redirection happen to Standard Page.
    }  
}
```

**V.F Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Sample__c" extensions="SampleOrderExtension" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="true" id="SampleOrderPage">
<apex:form id="mainForm">
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(recSaved == 'true' ,true, false)}"> //This part of code is just for the page which is displayed after save.
       <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:pageBlockButtons >
               <apex:commandButton id="editBtn" value="Edit" rendered="{!NOT(statusRFP)}" action="{!editSampleOrder}" />
               <apex:commandButton id="cloneBtn" value="Clone"  action="{!cloneSampleOrder}"/>
               <apex:commandButton id="cancelBtn" value="Cancel" rendered="{!NOT(statusRFP)}" action="{!cancel}"/>
               <apex:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Submit" rendered="{!NOT(statusRFP)}" onclick="ZendSumbitvalidation()" rerender="dummy, messagePanel"/>
                   <!--<apex:actionFunction name="ZendSumbitvalidation" action="{!updateStatus}" />  -->
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>
           <apex:pageBlockSection title="Sample Request Detail" columns="2" collapsible="false">
               <apex:outputField id="outputSampleName" value="{!soRecord.Name}"/>
<apex:outputField id="outEndEquipment" value="{!soRecord.End_Equipment__c}"/>

             <!--<apex:outputField id="outputAppName" value="{!soRecord.Application__c}"/>-->
                 <apex:outputField id="outEndCustomer" value="{!soRecord.End_Customer__c}" />

             <apex:outputField id="outputSAPSales" value="{!soRecord.SAP_Sales_Order_Number__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputCSO" value="{!soRecord.CSO__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputStatus" value="{!soRecord.Status__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputRSM" value="{!soRecord.RSM__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputEmailContact" value="{!soRecord.Email_cc_Contact__c}" />
               <apex:outputField id="outputPaidSample" value="{!soRecord.PAID_SAMPLE__c}" />
               <apex:outputField id="outputEmailUser" value="{!soRecord.Email_cc_User__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputSalesOrg" value="{!soRecord.Sales_Org__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputSpecialShipping" value="{!soRecord.SPECIAL_SHIPPING_INSTRUCTION_COMMENTS__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputPlatform" value="{!soRecord.Platform__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputDistributorNote" value="{!soRecord.Distributor_Note__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputaccOutput" value="{!soRecord.Account__c}"/>                                                        
               <apex:outputField id="outputshipTofield" label="Ship to Contact" value="{!soRecord.Ship_to__c}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="outputCustomerContact" value="{!soRecord.CUSTOMER_CONTACT__c}"/>
               <div>&nbsp;</div>                 
           <apex:pageblockSection id="inner1" columns="1" title="Customer Contact Address">
                    <apex:outputField label="Phone" value="{!soRecord.Customer_Contact_Phone__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id="outputContactAddress" label="Street/House Number" value="{!soRecord.Customer_Contact_Street_House_Number__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id="outputContactShippingCity" label="City" value="{!soRecord.Customer_Contact_City__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id="outputContactShippingState" label="State" value="{!soRecord.Customer_Contact_StateVisible__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id="outputContactShippingCountry" label="Country" value="{!soRecord.Customer_Contact_CountryVisible__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id="outputContactShippingPostalCode" label="Postal Code" value="{!soRecord.Customer_Contact_Postal_Code__c }"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        <apex:pageblockSection id="inner2" columns="1" title="Ship To Contact Address">
                    <apex:outputField label="Phone" value="{!soRecord.Shipping_Phone__c}"/> 
                    <apex:outputField id="outputAddress" value="{!soRecord.SHIP_TO_COMPANY_ADDRESS__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id="outputShippingCity" label="City" value="{!soRecord.ShippingCity__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id="outputShippingState" label="State" value="{!soRecord.Shipping_StateVisible__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id="outputShippingCountry" label="Country" value="{!soRecord.Shipping_CountryVisible__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputField id="outputShippingPostalCode" label="Postal Code" value="{!soRecord.ShippingPostalCode__c }"/> 

        </apex:pageblockSection>



               <apex:outputField id="CreatedBy" value="{!soRecord.CreatedById}"/>
               <apex:outputField id="LastModifiedBy" value="{!soRecord.LastModifiedById}"/> 
               <apex:outputField id="CreatedDate" value="{!soRecord.CreatedDate}"/> 
               <apex:outputField id="LastModifiedDate" value="{!soRecord.LastModifiedDate}"/> 

           </apex:pageblockSection>
           <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="compBlock">
               <c:SampleOrderRLComponent soExt="{!soExtObj}"></c:SampleOrderRLComponent>              
           </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel> 
    </div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Is there any way to modify the code to redirect back to the Standard page ?

**EDIT :** Snip for how record shows up now after save and how I need.

**NOW**

[image]

**Required**

[image]

Comment: what do you mean standard page? the salesforce page showing the recently saved record?

Comment: @MiczDomz  Yes. Upon save it should return back to the current record page. As of now the current record upon save is showing in the V.F page. But I want to show it in the standard page.

Answer (score 1):

This [URL hack](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/common-url-parameters);

```
    PageReference pr = new PageReference(...);
    pr.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
```

will present the standard layout-based page where the View action has been set to a Visualforce page.

Comment: I think any answer that recommends URL hacking without also mentioning this behavior is not supported is incomplete.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Fair point; I was incorrectly assuming hack would communicate some of that. "Not supported" is probably the wrong phrase though: it is supported in that it works today and perhaps the large number of people using the mechanism makes it hard for Salesforce to withdraw it even though they reserve the right to do so in the future. It is also hard to imagine what would prompt a change to the Visualforce URL patterns when Lightning is so unrelated to Visualforce and Lightning is where most change is.

Comment: @KeithC : The URL hack is also not working. The issue I feel is that in the save/cancel methods the 'RecordSaved' variable is set as TRUE which in turn is displaying up the v.f fields. Check this line .  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(recSaved == 'true' ,true, false)}"> . The view button on this object is not overwritten with the v.f page.

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this...

```
Apexpages.StandardController rateController;

public PageReference save() {

    currentrec = (Object__c) rateController.getRecord();
    try{
        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')==null){
            insert currentrec;
        } else {
            update currentrec;
        }
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+currentrec.Id);
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }catch (DmlException e){
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    } 

}
```