# Contact Role Addition Upon Opportunity Creation from Contact

Tags: opportunity, contact, opportunitycontactrole

I have a custom "New" Opportunity button in the Opportunity related list on Contacts. When this button is used, the Contact is not being added as a Contact Role to the resulting Opportunity? Two questions here. First, does the Standard button auto-add the originating Contact to the Opportunity as a Contact Role? Secondly, how can I make the custom button automatically add the originating Contact as a Contact Role on the resulting Opportunity? Thank you much.

Comment: For the first question, yes, the standard button does add the Contact as a primary Contact Role in the generated Opportunity. For the second one, please add some information about how your custom button is configured so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My code for the button is below, and it brings in some values automatically. I am just looking to add functionality assigning the Contact generating the Opportunity to the Contact Role. Thank you in advance.    
  
'/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Opportunity 
&save_new_url=%2F006%2Fe%3Flookupcmpgn%3D1%26 
&retURL={!Contact.Id} 
&accid={!Account.Id} 
&opp6={!Contact.LeadSource} 
&00Na0000009zQCa={!Contact.Lead_Source_sub_category__c} 
&00N1400000B8b6h={!Contact.Lead_Source_Note__c} 
&{!Opportunity.OwnerId}={!User.Id}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, yes, the standard button does add the Contact as a primary Contact Role in the generated Opportunity.

For the second question, you can add another URL parameter to get it populated, just add &conid={!Contact.Id} at the end. Like below:

> /setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Opportunity
>   &save_new_url=%2F006%2Fe%3Flookupcmpgn%3D1%26 &retURL={!Contact.Id}
>   &accid={!Account.Id} &opp6={!Contact.LeadSource}
>   &00Na0000009zQCa={!Contact.Lead_Source_sub_category__c}
>   &00N1400000B8b6h={!Contact.Lead_Source_Note__c}
>   &{!Opportunity.OwnerId}={!User.Id} &conid={!Contact.Id}

Comment: Thank you! Worked tremendously. I did not know the "conid" parameter. Is there a list of these button-programmable parameters that you know of? I'd love to not have to bother you folks much more on these types of asks.

Comment: According to this related topic: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/common-url-parameters there is no such list available.