# unable to get excel file in proper format when sending email

Tags: singleemailmessage

I had used in the controller:

```
a.setContentType('application/vnd.ms-excel');
```

but when i clicked a button to send the email with an attachment, i am getting all fields in one row.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Setting the ContentType doesn't perform any format conversion. A non `xls` attachment sent in this way will just have all the HTML dumped into the body of the spreadsheet.

I think the only way to get `xls` files from Salesforce is either:

1. <strike>from a Custom Report, where you know the Id and can form a download URL like `/00OG0000005YaRh?export&xf=xls`</strike>
2. or by hand-generating output tags compatible with the the [office XML format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205%28v=office.12%29.aspx) from a Visualforce Page.

Comment: #1 is not really a true Excel format, the program still complains that it was given a HTML file when you open it (but it does come pretty close and bit better than CSV). Force open it in text editor to inspect the source.

Comment: I just died inside :( thanks @eyescream, good spot

Answer (score 4):

I've been asked to try to generate "true" XLSX format as 2nd pass to make [Scheduled reports as attachment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/scheduled-reports-as-attachment) even friendlier. For sure it's not worth trying to emulate the old xls (binary) format...

I've spent some time searching and so far this thing looks most promising: http://neerajgupta999.blogspot.in/2012/06/multisheet-excel-from-apex.html.

If I'll have "version 2" of either the report export hack or something workable I promise to get back here and share ;)