# Send reports to emails not registered in Salesforce

Tags: reporting

Is there a way to send the output from a report to email addresses that are not assigned to a Salesforce account?  We have some part-time athletic coaches that need to receive information on contacts in Salesforce, but have no need to have Salesforce accounts.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Add-on:  We found a thread in success.salesforce.com that discussed setting up a general user (to get the email address set up) and send the reports there, which could use the autoforwarding process to distribute the emails to other email addresses.  Wondering if anyone took that approach and if it worked out for them.

Comment: You can print it as PDF with PDF creator save it in you computer and send it via email

Answer (score 6):

Officially, it's NOT possible (at least no direct way to do so). But there are multiple hacks available such as [this](http://sfdc-heretic.warped-minds.com/2006/04/10/progmatic-access-to-salesforcecom-reports/) which have worked well for me in the past. You can scrape it as a CSV document. This approach is also discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277332/how-to-i-access-reports-programmatically-in-salesforce-using-apex) Stackoverflow thread.

As for the (lack of) official support, this idea is being tracked [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gu6PAAQ).

Comment: I was quite succesful with scraping the CSVs and creating something that can be used in VF email templates: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/scheduled-reports-as-attachment Analytics API sounds very promising but the limitation to 2K records is somewhat disappointing...

Comment: This answer is very link-ish. I understand the intent, because there's a lot of content, but some little teaser of what each link is instead of just non-descript "this" links would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to send reports to any email address using Salesforce's declarative tools, only to users. One option here might be an app and custom UI that uses the Analytics API. While certainly not a turnkey solution, it offers API access to underlying report data that you could then build your own UI around.

[Analytics API Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/salesforce_analytics_rest_api.pdf)

[Using the Salesforce Analytics API on a Visualforce Page](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/09/using-the-salesforce-analytics-api-on-a-visualforce-page.html)

Comment: How do I find out more about this proposed solution?

Comment: I've added a couple of examples to my post, including the link to the dev guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Conga Courier](http://www.congamerge.com/products/courier) to distribute reports to anyone. It is a paid add-on to Salesforce.

Comment: or Conga Composer/Conductor for added flexibility (at a modest additional cost). Conga has terrific support (including phone support)

Answer (score 1):

You can also send the report to yourself (assuming you're a licensed user) and use your email client to forward it appropriately.  Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and good solution, and free

https://reportbuilder.cloud4j.com/login

Allows you to send and schedule these reports.

Answer (score -1):

One pretty solid workaround is to provision the non-user a Chatter Free license. That makes them a "user" enough that you can add them to reports.

Comment: This no longer works unfortunately.