# Question about generated Excel Reports

Tags: reporting, excel

"Copyright (c) 2000-2014 salesforce,com, inc, All rights reserved"

This is what shows up when I export my report to an Excel file. Is it possible to change this? If it is (through a salesforce provided way) I suppose it is legal to do it?

Best regards

Comment: If you'll be fetching the report output to Apex you could use something similar to my `prettify` function: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/scheduled-reports-as-attachment. No idea if we actually violate something by cutting it off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't wait until Spring '14 release, I've heard that you can file a case with Salesforce to have them remove it as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the standard UI, there is no way to change this value (there's actually five lines of text that is exported). You have to remove this manually after the export, or use a custom Visualforce page/Apex Code class to remove the text beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to export reports without the footer is one of the enhancements in Spring 14.