# Scheduled reports to be sent to an specific email address (not a licensed user)?

Tags: reporting

We need to schedule some reports to be sent every month to an specific email address. Is it possible to an email address that does not belong to a licensed user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scheduled report email can be sent to *only* licensed SFDC user. If you really want to share report to list of non SFDC users, you may want to create a group email id and assign this email id under a SFDC user. Now let your schedule report sends email to the user which has group email id.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can schedule reports to be sent to self-service portal user accounts as well as full licensed accounts.. so you could use a portal licence "user" to do this.

Edit: Having googled about for it there are a couple of (paid) apps for this on the appexchange too (which means it must be technically possible!)

Comment: also non-paid if you can live with csv version: http://kevindotcar.wix.com/home/apps/blog/how-to-schedule-a-report-to-send and a more flexible (but extensive!) one here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/scheduled-reports-as-attachment

Answer (score 1):

You can create Chatter Free accounts for email addresses where you want to send reports. Obviously, this would only work if you don't mind giving Chatter access to the owner of the email address.

This has worked well for us. In our case, we needed to send reports to a bunch of internal employees. Some of those employees are in different departments and don't have or need access to Salesforce (either full license or Chatter). So we created an email list of all employees that needed access to the report and then created a Chatter free account for the email address associated with the email list.

Answer (score 0):

In our experience, most recipients who are not licensed SFDC users want to see the scheduled report sent to them as an Excel file. For this use case, we use the AppExchange vendor AppExtremes; products: `Conga Courier` or `Conga Composer`.  Pricing is based on volume of reports sent per month. Vendor (I have no affiliation) provides the best technical support I have ever seen (free phone support no less).