# How to get more than 2000 records in case of schedule reports to our email in Salesforce?

Tags: reporting, customization, reports-api

I have a report with more than 2000 recodes and scheduled weekly. As per Salesforce standard limitations we get only 2000 records to our email. Is there any possibility to get more records? please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question, **you can't.** This is because the Salesforce native functionality won't give you more than 2,000 rows in a scheduled HTML email and this can't be worked around by coding a custom solution since the [Analytics API](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter14/AnalyticsAPI) limitation is also [2,000 rows per report](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BKDaIAO).

My view is that the 2,000 row limit is currently in place for good reasons. Firstly, there are [Email limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_general.htm&language=en) in Salesforce. The maximum size of a single email sent from Salesforce is currently 25MB. If the limit was increased beyond 2,000 rows, then that would potentially be beyond the 25MB limit.

Secondly, generally speaking, HTML email reports are quite burdensome to use and some organizations may not even permit them in the first place due to [potential security risks](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003665&language=en_US).

So, what's the best approach? Sending a scheduled email with an attachment would be the best approach, in my opinion. [Cloud4J](http://www.cloud4j.com/) offer a very solid tool at an excellent price to achieve this. Furthermore, you could code this solution too. A great starting link with code examples is [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/scheduled-reports-as-attachment).

It's a shame that sending an attachment isn't already a Salesforce feature however, as per the [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Brb6AAC), it is on 'the road map' with a huge number of votes.

Lastly, there is also an Idea to increase the Salesforce HTML report row limit beyond 2,000 [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Xt0YAAS) but due to the above reasons, I am not sure this will be increased anytime soon.

I hope this helps.